# VB returning overflow with small numbers

Tags: vb.net, image, overflow

After spending an hour trying to solve this problem, I decided to as a question.

I'm using VB.Net 2010 in an image related project. In this step I have to compare the color of the pixels of two images to determine how similar they are. To do so I designed the following code:

```
            ''get both images as bitmaps

            Dim act As New Bitmap("cam.bmp")
            Dim map As New Bitmap(bmap)

            ''declare the variable that counts the different pixels

            Dim count As Integer = 0

            ''declare the variables that represent the colors

            Dim val As Long = 0
            Dim valr As Long = 0
            Dim valg As Long = 0
            Dim valb As Long = 0

            ''analize both images pixel by pixel

            For x = 1 To act.Width - 1 Step 1

                For y = 1 To act.Height - 1 Step 1

                    valr = 0
                    valg = 0
                    valb = 0

                    ''determine how different the pixels are

                    valr = Math.Abs(act.GetPixel(x, y).R - map.GetPixel(x, y).R)
                    valg = Math.Abs(act.GetPixel(x, y).G - map.GetPixel(x, y).G)
                    valb = Math.Abs(act.GetPixel(x, y).B - map.GetPixel(x, y).B)

                    val = Long.Parse(Int((valr + valg + valb) / 3).ToString)

                    ''if enough different, add 1 to count

                    If val > 50 Then

                        count += 1

                    End If

                Next

            Next

            ''show how many pixels are different in proportion

            MsgBox((count / (act.Width * act.Height)).ToString)
```

When this code runs, an overflow occurs in the `valr = Math.Abs(act.GetPixel(x, y).R - map.GetPixel(x, y).R)` part. No other problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `GetPixel` returns a `Color` and `Color.R` returns a `Byte`. When you subtract one byte from another, the result is a byte, but bytes are unsigned and can't hold a negative value. If the second value is larger than the first,  You get the OverflowException before your `Math.Abs` method is ever called.

To avoid that, you can use `CInt` to convert the Bytes to Integer before subtracting them.

```
valr = Math.Abs(CInt(act.GetPixel(x, y).R) - CInt(map.GetPixel(x, y).R))
valg = Math.Abs(CInt(act.GetPixel(x, y).G) - CInt(map.GetPixel(x, y).G))
valb = Math.Abs(CInt(act.GetPixel(x, y).B) - CInt(map.GetPixel(x, y).B))
```